# How to configure ESLint to follow Angular best practices?

Tags: angular, eslint, eslintrc

I have an angular project and I've just installed ESLint, however I don't know what my .eslintrc.json file should contain. I've gone through the `npx eslint --init` command but I'm not sure if that is all I need to do?

I want ESLint to recommend my code follows Angular's best practice guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how is everything ?

There are some patterns you can follow, for example I use Airbnb, the configuration is simple:

```
npm i eslint-config-airbnb
```

The following link explains the guide line and the examples:
https://github.com/airbnb/javascript

For more information, Complete instructions:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-config-airbnb